# “L'industrie du vêtement” or “l'industrie de la mode”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, habillement

When I consult the dictionary I do not get a distinction between the textile industry and the fashion industry. Do these two industries share the same word in French or is there actually a distinction?

For example in :

> Je travaille dans l'industrie de la mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the same distinction than in english. The fashion industry is often close to the textile industry, but you could also be designing fashion jewels or theorically photographing fashion screwdrivers.

Comment: This answer doesn't even give the French words for *fashion industry* and *textile industry*, and the question doesn't tell what translations you have found in the dictionary.

Comment: And *"travailler dans la mode"* could mean you are a photographer, a model, or a Chinese worker sewing Hermès scarfs in a cellar. So with all these approximations, *mode* stands for *fashion* and *textile* stands for *textile*. *Je travaille dans la mode*, *je travaille dans le textile*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps The answer doesn't give the French words for fashion industry and textile industry because it is not what is asked.

Comment: +1 for fashion screwdrivers

Answer (score -1):

You can use “Je travaille dans la mode”.